# Adding geom_hline to density plot using coord_polar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I need to add a reference line to my density plot using R and **ggplot2**.

Because I'm using polar coordinates, this should make a circle in the middle of my plot. I use `geom_hline(yintercept = .5)` but no line shows up on my plot when I add `coord_polar()`.

Here is my code.

```
ggplot(flights_sample2, aes(x = radians, fill = factor(nf, levels = c(8:0)))) +
    geom_bar(binwidth = pi/18, position = "fill") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2*pi), breaks = c(0,pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2), 
                                            labels = c("N", "E", "S", "W")) +
    coord_polar() + 
    xlim(0,2*pi) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = .5)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

If you first set up the reference with geom_line and then add coord_polar() you can get a reference circle:

```
xx=seq(0,2*pi,length=10)
yy=rep(2,10)
g <- ggplot(flights_sample2, aes(x = radians, fill = factor(nf, levels = c(8:0)))) +
    geom_bar(binwidth = pi/18, position = "fill") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2*pi), breaks = c(0,pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2), 
                                            labels = c("N", "E", "S", "W")) +
        xlim(0,2*pi) + 
    geom_hline(aes(x=xx, y=yy))

g+coord_polar()
```

Obviously this wasn't tested with your data and code, but it worked with the example in the help(coord_polar) page